# Reactive Extensions swallows exceptions from OnNext() called on a thread pool thread?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I use Rx 2 in .Net 4.5.  When the following code runs, it just exits silently without executing the OnCompleted delegate or showing any errors.  If I use `Scheduler.CurrentThread` in `ToObservable`, it will at least throw the error and terminate the program, at which point not executing OnCompleted makes sense.  But when this is executed in a thread other than the main one, this behavior seems unreasonable and unacceptable.  Do I miss anything?

```
static void Main()
{
     Enumerable.Range(0, 1)
                           .ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
                           .Subscribe(o => { throw new Exception("blah"); }, () => Console.WriteLine("completed"));

     Thread.Sleep(2000);
 }
```

**Edited:**
Yes, when running as a console app, it will always throw the error regardless of what thread the observation is executed on.

However, when I run this code as a test in NUnit as follows, it exits silently after 2 seconds (thread sleep time) without any error or message (expecting "completed").  So is it actually NUnit causing the issue?

```
[TestFixture]
class Program
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1)
                .ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
                .Subscribe(
                    o => { throw new Exception("blah"); }, 
                    () => Console.WriteLine("completed"));
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rx does not catch exceptions thrown by observers.  This is a very important design principle that has been discussed in length before, though for some reason it's only included as a footnote of §6.4 in the [Rx Design Guidelines](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219).

> **Note:** do not protect calls to *Subscribe*, *Dispose*, *OnNext*, *OnError* and *OnCompleted* methods. These calls are on the edge of the monad. Calling the *OnError* method from these places will lead to unexpected behavior.

Essentially, this guideline ensures that, from the perspective of an observer, **OnError** will only be called by exceptions originating from the observable itself, including any calls to user code that participate directly in the computation (rather than merely observing the results).  If this were not the case, then an observer may not be able to distinguish whether an exception passed to **OnError** is a bug in their **OnNext** handler or perhaps a bug in the observable.

But more importantly, it also ensures that any exception thrown by an **OnNext** handler goes unhandled.  This makes it easier to debug your program and protects user data.

That being said, the reason why you may be observing different behavior when **OnNext** is executed on a pooled thread is simply a consequence of your debugging experience.  Try enabling [first-chance exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx).

Furthermore, I'd also avoid the race condition by changing `Thread.Sleep` to `Console.ReadKey()`.

Comment: Also try running without the debugger attached and you'll see the behavior that you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks, @DaveSexton. Yes, running as console app is fine; what is not is actually in an NUnit test.  Pls see my edited question.

Comment: It's a race condition.  I already stated that you should avoid using Thread.Sleep.

Comment: To be clear, you're asking an entirely different question now: "How do I run concurrency tests in NUnit?"

Comment: Furthermore, you should not expect OnCompleted to be called.  As I stated, Rx does NOT catch the exception thrown by your observer.  As a result, the observable halts immediately.  There are no more notifications.

Answer (score 4):

Exceptions thrown in the Subscribe block have Undefined Behavior. If you are doing something that can throw, you need to wrap that in a `Select` or `SelectMany` (or just wrap the code in a try-catch).

Comment: The exception's not being thrown by **Subscribe**, it's being thrown by **OnNext**.  The Rx Design Guidelines makes this behavior quite clear: exceptions are not handled.  Anyway, I'm not sure how **Select** would help.  It would just push the exception into **OnError**, which he doesn't provide a handler for and thus it would just be thrown again anyway.  (And it also goes against the recommendations of the guidelines.)

Comment: @DaveSexton You're right that it would still crash, I'm giving more general advice on what to do when you want to run code that may throw.

Comment: Well that's fine of course, but I also disagreed with your advice in particular.  It's purely constructive criticism.  I explained in my answer that the recommendation in Rx is not catching exceptions thrown by observers and redirecting them to OnError.  If the OP's observer may throw, then they should not change to the **Select** operator to allow the exception to be caught by Rx because 1) it renders exceptions less useful 2) it renders **OnError** less useful and makes it error prone itself 3) it's semantically incorrect to use a projection operator merely for this purpose.