# Proper pattern for chain of transformations (pipeline) on an observable stream?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming

I have the following scenario:

- given a stream of objects `IObservable<E>`
- process each `E` to obtain either `E1` or an error state, in which case I need error message `M1`
- process each `E1` to obtain either `E2` or an error message `M2`
- ....

There's an additional complication in that the result En and/or the error message `Mn` can depend on *all* values `E`, `E1`, ..., `En-1` - not only on `En-1`.

Given all that, is there a better pattern than what I'm using?

[Edit] As requested, I have added a fully working example; unfortunately that made this post quite large.

```
internal class Program
{
  private static void Main()
  {
    var stream = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Record { Id = i }).ToObservable();

    stream
      .Select(it => new ComplexType { Item = it })
      .SelectIfOk(Process1)
      .SelectIfOk(Process2)
      .SelectIfOk(ProcessN)
      .Subscribe(DisplayResult);

    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  private static ComplexType Process1(ComplexType data)
  {
    // do some processing
    data.E1 = data.Item.Id * 10;

    // check for errors in output
    if (data.E1 == 30 || data.E1 == 70)
    {
      data.Errors.Add("Error");
    }

    return data;
  }

  private static ComplexType Process2(ComplexType data)
  {
    // do some processing
    data.E2 = (data.E1 - 3).ToString();

    // check for errors in output
    // can generate multiple errors for the same item
    if (data.E2.StartsWith("4"))
    {
      // does not only depend on the immediate precursor, E1 in this case
      data.Errors.Add("Starts with 4 -- " + data.Item.Id);
    }

    if (data.E2.StartsWith("8"))
    {
      data.Errors.Add("Starts with 8");
    }

    return data;
  }

  private static ComplexType ProcessN(ComplexType data)
  {
    // do some processing
    data.EN = "Success " + data.E2;

    // this one doesn't generate errors
    return data;
  }

  private static void DisplayResult(ComplexType data)
  {
    if (data.Errors.Any())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0:##0} has errors: " + string.Join(",", data.Errors));
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0:##0}: {1}", data.Item.Id, data.EN);
    }
  }
}
```

These are the classes used in the above code sample:

```
public class Record
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FullName { get; set; }
  public string OtherStuff { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexType
{
  public Record Item { get; set; }

  // intermediary results
  public int E1 { get; set; }
  public string E2 { get; set; }

  // final result
  public string EN { get; set; }

  public List<string> Errors { get; set; }

  public ComplexType()
  {
    Errors = new List<string>();
  }
}
```

Note that there is no relationship between the types of `E1`, `E2`, ..., `En` (in particular, they don't all inherit the same common type).

`SelectIfOk` is an extension method:

```
public static IObservable<T> SelectIfOk<T>(this IObservable<T> observable,
  Func<T, T> selector)
  where T : ComplexType
{
  return observable.Select(item => item.Errors.Any() ? item : selector(item));
}
```

The result of running this code is:

```
1: Success 7
2: Success 17
3 has errors: Error
4: Success 37
5 has errors: Starts with 4 -- 5
6: Success 57
7 has errors: Error
8: Success 77
9 has errors: Starts with 8
10: Success 97
```

I am using ComplexType so that I can carry both the intermediary results and the error state and it just looks... fishy. I've been staring at that code for a week (it's for a hobby project) and I keep feeling like I'm missing the proper way of doing things with Rx.

[Edit] I forgot to mention a very important thing: it is imperative that I process *all* items in the stream, even if some of them generate errors; that's why I cannot just use the `Subscribe` overload that takes an exception - it will complete the stream. Abandoning one item when there's an error is fine (if `Process1` generates an error then `Process2`, ..., `ProcessN` are no longer executed), but not abandoning the entire stream.

[Edit] Another clarification: if it helps, the processing I have in mind would be more naturally suited to the TPL DataFlow library, except that I'm limited to .NET 4.0 so I can't use it.

Incidentally, I have been unable to find any serious discussion of error handling in Rx, usually there's a mention of a `Subscribe` overload / the `OnError` call and that's it. Does anyone have a recommendation for an in-depth approach of the subject?

Comment: Do you know of all ProcessN ahead of time? Or do you require the **Select** operator because of its laziness?

Comment: I know all ProcessN ahead of time; I'm using Select because it takes a Func that allows me to transform E into E1 and so on.

Comment: I added a new edit to the description.

Comment: Data from a stream can be thought of as a message.  In which case this is simply a pipe with several filters (http://www.eaipatterns.com/PipesAndFilters.html).  I would suggest that you make this more object-oriented and composable by separating the filters out and giving them meaningful names and "composing" the pipe in multiple steps instead of declaratively with a "builder" like pattern chaining extension methods. (e.g. a collection of `Func<IObserable<T>, IObservable<T>>` that your iterate starting with your first IObservable<T>`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do... apply successive transformations to each item in the stream. My question was: is the above code ok, or is there a "canonical" way using Rx? (The filters _are_ separated out, that's what the ProcessN methods are.)

Comment: I have not seen a specific example of pipes and filters with Rx

Comment: Looking closer at your implementation of `SelectIfOk` it appears that originally you're simply trying to implement error propagation, but then your edit states "it is imperative that I process all items in the stream, even if some of them generate errors", which I took to mean that every process sees every event, regardless of errors. So which is it?

Comment: What I meant is: I cannot throw from the `ProcessN` methods, because that would complete the stream. Instead, I need a way to transform it into an error message and continue processing the next item. Once an error has occurred, the rest of the `ProcessN` methods don't make any sense anymore, hence me skipping the `selector()` call in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing all `ProcessN` ahead of time means that you can get rid of the multiple `Select` operators, simplifying the query and revealing your true intention.

```
stream.Select(e => Process(e));

...

? Process(E e)
{
  // Process1, Process2, ...ProcessN
}
```

Now we see that this isn't a reactive problem. It's more like an interactive aggregation problem.

You also haven't mentioned what kind of output you ultimately need to observe in **Subscribe**, though I'll just assume that it's the aggregated result of the processes.

To define the return type, we first need to define the return type of `ProcessN`. Instead of using your `ComplexType`, I'll use a type with better semantics for now:

```
Either<E, Exception> Process(?);
```

So each `ProcessN` function may return either an `E` or an `Exception` (without throwing).

Furthermore, according to your requirements each `ProcessN` must receive the current result of the running aggregation as its input. So just like your definition above, we must replace the ? with a list of the return values of the `ProcessN` functions called before it.

```
Either<E, Exception> Process(IList<Either<E, Exception>> results);
```

Now we can define the return type of the aggregator (defined above):

```
IList<Either<E, Exception>> Process(E e)
{
  // Process1, Process2, ...ProcessN
}
```

The body of the aggregator can be implemented as follows:

```
IList<Either<E, Exception>> Process(E e)
{
  var results = new List<Either<E, Exception>>();
  results.Add(Process1(results.AsReadOnly()));
  results.Add(Process2(results.AsReadOnly()));
  ...
  results.Add(ProcessN(results.AsReadOnly()));
  return results.AsReadOnly();
}
```

### Error Handling in Rx

Start by reading the [Rx Design Guidelines](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219).

[Intro to Rx](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html#AdvancedErrorHandling) has a section on error handling operators.

Here are some in-depth discussions/comments on error handling semantics and contracts in Rx:

- [About the contracts in Rx](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee5dba5d-eea9-4d85-8f58-c2e1c71ef33a/about-the-contracts-in-rx-exceptions-and-blocking?forum=rx)
- [Rx++ bug?! Catching OnNext exceptions (Discussion is broader than Rx++)](https://rx.codeplex.com/discussions/430625)
- [Reactive Extensions swallows exceptions from OnNext() called on a thread pool thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825981/reactive-extensions-swallows-exceptions-from-onnext-called-on-a-thread-pool-th)
- [Exception handling and EventArgs.Error (WCF but with broader application)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3d38a15d-35f3-4993-97df-bdc435b2785b/exception-handling-and-eventargserror?forum=rx)

(Full disclosure: I've contributed to all of these particular discussions.)

Comment: Hmm... ok, two problems. One, I guess I was unclear on something - ProcessN depends on the result of the previous steps, but for a single item - it has to receive E, E1, ..., En and not the list of all previously processed items. Two, getting rid of a single method is what I'm trying to do here - I have one method that is over 100 lines long, and calls sub-methods, and I want to replace it with a pipeline to clarify its intent. (Thanks for the articles, I'll read through them.)

Comment: Your description still seems unclear to me. Are you saying that `E1` is the output of `Process1` or it's the final output of the entire computation, `ProcessN`? Your original `Select` chain implies that E->Process1->E1->Process2->E2->...ProcessN->EN, but now it seems like you're saying that every `E*` is actually the previous result of `ProcessN`; e.g., E->Process1->Process2->...ProcessN->E1, E1->Process1->Process2->...ProcessN->E2, etc. Is that correct?

Comment: E1 = P1(E), E2 = P2(E, E1), E3 = P3(E, E1, E2), ..., En = Pn(E, E1, E2, ..., En-1)

Comment: Right, so I'm still unclear as to how my answer is wrong. Maybe you can clear it up by providing a [short but complete example](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html), including the output expected. I'd like to see what `ComplexType` looks like and a working example of `Process1`.

Comment: The `Either<>` makes sense, but I don't understand the point of the `List<Either<E, Exception>>`. `P1` returns an `E1`, not an `E` (and the types are not related).

Comment: Ah, well then use different letters next time! I read E1 as something like E(prime), but instead you meant: 
`U = P1(T); V = P2(T, U); W = P3(T, U, V);`
I think my answer still applies if all types {T, U, V, W} derive from a base class `E`.

Comment: Or you can swap your `ComplexType` for `Either`, though my point still stands about the chain of `Select` operators being unnecessary and confusing, it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

When I asked this question I was not aware of the `Notification<T>` class and the `Materialize` method in Rx. Here is the solution I came up with - it solves primarily the "pipeline" aspect of the problem, but I can solve the "depends on intermediate results" aspect by using tuples:

```
private static void Main()
{
  var source = new Subject<int>();

  source
    .Materialize()
    .SelectIfOk(Process1)
    .SelectIfOk(Process2)
    .Subscribe(it =>
      Console.WriteLine(it.HasValue
        ? it.Value.ToString()
        : it.Exception != null ? it.Exception.Message : "Completed."));

  source.OnNext(1);
  source.OnNext(2);
  source.OnNext(3);
  source.OnNext(4);
  source.OnNext(5);
  source.OnCompleted();

  Console.ReadLine();
}

private static int Process1(int value)
{
  if (value == 3)
    throw new Exception("error 1");

  // do some processing
  return value * 2;
}

private static string Process2(int value)
{
  if (value == 4)
    throw new Exception("error 2");

  // do some processing
  return value + " good";
}

private static IObservable<Notification<TR>> SelectIfOk<T, TR>(this IObservable<Notification<T>> stream,
  Func<T, TR> selector)
{
  Func<T, Notification<TR>> trySelector = it =>
  {
    try
    {
      var value = selector(it);
      return Notification.CreateOnNext(value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      return Notification.CreateOnError<TR>(ex);
    }
  };

  return stream.Select(it =>
    it.HasValue
      ? trySelector(it.Value)
      : it.Exception != null
        ? Notification.CreateOnError<TR>(it.Exception)
        : Notification.CreateOnCompleted<TR>());
}
```

If I want to use the intermediate results then, as I said, I will use tuples:

```
private static Tuple<int, string> Process2(int value)
{
  if (value == 4)
    throw new Exception("error 2");

  // do some processing
  return Tuple.Create(value, value * 3 + " good");
}

private static string Process3(Tuple<int, string> value)
{
  return value.Item1 + " -> " + value.Item2;
}
```

(I need to add `.SelectIfOk(Process3)` to the pipeline.)

I am reluctant to mark my own answer as being correct, so I'll leave this open for a while; however, as far as I can tell it does fulfill my requirements.